# GitHub API error in getting profile

Tags: node.js, passport.js, github-api

I am working with GitHub API and using passport js.
Using passport example code https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github/tree/master/examples/login

However it's validating user, I am able to get access token and all but while fetching profile it throws the following error

```
InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile
   at /Users/tesco/Downloads/temp-master/node_modules/passport-github2/lib/strategy.js:100:19
   at passBackControl (/Users/tesco/Downloads/temp-master/node_modules/passport-github2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:123:9)
   at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/tesco/Downloads/temp-master/node_modules/passport-github2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7)
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
   at _stream_readable.js:908:16
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I am trying it for enterprise git , so I modified auth url to 
https://github.dev.global.ENTERPRISE_NAME.org/login/oauth/authorize

Comment: not enough info to answer question, however git enterprise api's have different url's for profile , check https://developer.github.com/v3/enterprise/

Comment: I cloned passport git example and in node-modules>passport-github2>lib>strategy.js modified this `options.authorizationURL`

however profile url is `this._userProfileURL = options.userProfileURL || 'https://api.github.com/user';`

Answer (score 0):

ur profile api will be somewhat like

```
https://github.dev.global.ENTERPRISE_NAME.org/api/v3/user
```

email api like

```
https://github.dev.global.ENTERPRISE_NAME.org/api/v3/user/emails
```